# Bandwidth calculation for density function

Tags: r, density-function, density-estimation

How is the bandwidth = 1.399776  calculated for the R function `density()` in this example ?

```
x <- c(-3.5, 0.0, 0.5, 6.0) 
density(x)$bw

[1] 1.399776
```

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation? `density` function has several rule-of-thumb functions for calculating bandwidth, it depends which one do you use. It is all well documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard bandwidth function used by `density()` is `bw.nrd0()`. It uses the formula
$$bw=0.9n^{-\frac15}\cdot\min\left(sd(x),\frac{IQR(x)}{1.34}\right),$$
where $n$ is the sample size, $sd()$ denotes the sample standard deviation and $IQR()$ is the interquartile range function, i.e. it calculates the difference between the upper and the lower quartile: $q_{0.75}-q_{0.25}$. The motivation behind this is that the expected value of the IQR of normally distributed samples is $2q_{0.75}\sigma\approx 1.34$, where $\sigma$ is the sample's standard deviation.

Altogether, the bandwidth function is pretty much just a rescaled standard deviation.
Its code is

```
function (x) 
{
    if (length(x) < 2L) 
        stop("need at least 2 data points")
    hi <- sd(x)
    if (!(lo <- min(hi, IQR(x)/1.34)))    #if IQR=0, use sd(), abs(x[1L]) or 1 as bw
        (lo <- hi) || (lo <- abs(x[1L])) || (lo <- 1)
    0.9 * lo * length(x)^(-0.2)
}
```